# What is the default boolean value in C#?

Tags: c#

A boolean (`bool`) can't be null. And:

```
bool foo; if(foo){} // Use of unassigned local variable 'foo'
```

Why the default value is not false? So what is the value if it is not null?
What is the reason?

Edit 1 - The default value is indeed false - but all variable should be initialized, why? this is for another question ;)

Edit 2 - with Resharper : `private bool foo = false; // Initializing field by default value is redundant` ???

Comment: You might find http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/12/absence-of-evidence-is-not-evidence-of-absence.aspx interesting

Answer (score 110, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx

> Remember that using uninitialized variables in C# is not allowed.

With

```
bool foo = new bool();
```

foo will have the default value.

Boolean default is **false**

Comment: Sorry, added: Remember that using uninitialized variables in C# is not allowed.  As seen in the linked article

Comment: Thanks! and so how you can explain my "Edit 2" :)

Comment: the default value will be set if the default constructor is called. You just initialized a new variable with a value.  "int i" will throw the same error -Use of unassigned local variable-. Set the value at initializing or call the default constructor. so you will not have any problems :)

Comment: @Destructor I think your comment is slightly confusing. The reason resharper is suggesting that OP does not have to initialize the boolean field is because fields in a class are automatically assigned their default value, which local variables are not. See the [answer from Hasan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6855795/681538) below.

Answer (score 31):

Basically local variables aren't automatically initialized. Hence using them without initializing would result in an exception.

Only the following variables are automatically initialized to their default values:

- Static variables
- Instance variables of class and struct instances
- Array elements

The default values are as follows (assigned in default constructor of a class):

- The default value of a variable of reference type is null.
- For integer types, the default value is 0
- For char, the default value is `\u0000'
- For float, the default value is 0.0f
- For double, the default value is 0.0d
- For decimal, the default value is 0.0m
- For bool, the default value is false
- For an enum type, the default value is 0
- For a struct type, the default value is obtained by setting all value type fields to their default values

As far as later parts of your question are conerned:

- The reason why all variables which are not automatically initialized to default values should be initialized is a restriction imposed by compiler.
- private bool foo = false; This is indeed redundant since this is an instance variable of a class. Hence this would be initialized to false in the default constructor. Hence no need to set this to false yourself.

Comment: For completeness, the [default value table at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/83fhsxwc.aspx) says that default values for struct types also includes setting "all reference-type fields to null."

Answer (score 10):

The default value is indeed false.

However you can't use a local variable is it's not been assigned first.

You can use the default keyword to verify:

```
bool foo = default(bool);
if (!foo) { Console.WriteLine("Default is false"); }
```

Answer (score 4):

The default value for bool is `false`. See [this table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx) for a great reference on default values. The only reason it would not be false when you check it is if you initialize/set it to true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (using default keyword)

```
 bool foo = default(bool); if (foo) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be treated as defensive programming approach from the compiler - the variables must be assigned before it can be used.