# Strange behavior in C# for value types

Tags: c#, .net, types, unassigned-variable

I just tried a small code snippet to see how value type initialization works.
Below is the code snippet

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            int num;
            char alpha;
            //if (num == null)
            //{
            //    // this is null
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    string value = num.ToString();
            //}

        }
```

Some codes are commented intentionally to build the project correctly. The compilation which was coming was

```
Use of unassigned local variable 'num'
```

I know all variables should be assigned before use. But when I debugged this found that num has the value 0. If this is by default initialized to 0 then why do we need to assign some value always before using it.

Would it have been a `nullable` type I understand the risk of using a unassigned variable which will through an exception.

Now suppose I want to use the zero value of num which is already available without any assignment, why is it mandatory for me to initialize the num?

Someone can say that this is how .NET/C# works. But there must be some strong reason behind this. Can you please tell this reason?

Answer (score 0):

Member variables will be initialized to the default value according to their type!
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx) is a list of them.

```
public MyClass()
{
   int number; //will be initialized to zero
}
```

However, local variables (in functions) will not be initialized to the default value by the compiler, therefore it is not allowed to use them!

```
public void myFunction()
{
   int number; //will NOT be initialized to zero
}
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233000/why-compile-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable) a reference to the same question on stackoverflow..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a field, then you can leave it uninitialized and then use without problem, because field will be a **memory variable** and it will be initialized to 0 automatically (during initialization). Same doesn't work with local variables, as compiler may decide to hold its value in the **register** and this is why you need to set its value into default impicitly, or it will have some "random" value upon first use (left from previous use of that register), because registers are not cleared automatically.

This behavior is common for C-languages and I don't see why would in C# it should be different.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the whole int range and you want to have a extra option use `int?` that's a nullable type, all primals with a ? on it is a nullable type, for an example if you need true, false and both a `bool?` could be used.