# Why is the int default value not taken during runtime?

Tags: c#, .net

During the declaration of *local* variables, they are stored on the stack and memory is also allocated the same time. In case of int, it takes its default value 0.

And MSDN states "uninitialized variables in C# is not allowed" and so it takes its default value. 0 as in case of an int.

But if I write a code like int a; int b=a; I will get an error like "use of unassigned local variable a". In this case why is it not taking the default value 0?

Comment: "use of unassigned local variable a" is probably a warning unless you have set it to show as an error.

Comment: @ckv no it is an [error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d.aspx)

Comment: why do you use int b = a if you want b to be default?

Comment: Please show *exactly* which bit of MSDN you're referring to. I think you're talking about fields, not local variables. Local variables do *not* get default values.

Comment: Variables must always be initialized, hence the error. Properties, however, do not need to be. An uninitialized integer property will not complain when accessed, and will simply return the default 0 as you expect.

Comment: Have a look at this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233000/why-compile-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable)

Comment: @YaugenVlasau I simply wrote the code to explain the scenario more clearly. If int a has default value 0 and if MSDN tells like "uninitialized variables in C# is not allowed", why we are getting an error for the statement int b=a;? Why its not taking the default value 0?

Comment: If you people write a method and inside that write int a; When debugging you can see its value as 0. Then why a manual initialization is needed to use that variable?

Comment: @VishnuY : Because that's how the compiler is written. In purest technical terms, it might not be necessary, but the compiler won't let you. Why? Because that's how it is. It prevents a whole bunch of bugs that might otherwise slip through the net.

Comment: you are right the compiler gives you that error. so you have no options rather then assign a. for example: int a = default(int);