# Settings control position at runtime from name

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a list of controls and their locations in a datatable and I would like to go through the whole datatable and set the location of each control.  The difficulty I have is defining which control I want to set the location for.
For example one can set the location of a control as follows:

```
button1.Location = new Point(xpos, Ypos);
button2.Location = new Point(xpos, Ypos);
```

The thing is that I can't hard code the names of all the controls before hand.  This is the code that I currently use:  The datatable contains one row for every control in the form, and has three columns: the control name, the x location and the y location.

```
int rowPosition = 0;
Control x;
string controlName;
int xCoord;
int yCoord;

foreach (DataRow row in dtControlPosition.Rows)
{                
    controlName = dtControlPosition.Rows[rowPosition]["Control"].ToString();

    xCoord = Convert.ToInt32(dtControlPosition.Rows[rowPosition]["XCoord"].ToString());

    yCoord = Convert.ToInt32(dtControlPosition.Rows[rowPosition]["YCoord"].ToString());

    // don't have any idea what to do here:
    // I tried x.Name = controlName
    // x.Location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(xCoord),Convert.toInt32(yCoord));

    rowPosition = rowPosition +1;
}
```

When I try the above I receive an error "use of unassigned local variable "x"."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why compile error "Use of unassigned local variable"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233000/why-compile-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable)

Comment: you created a variable like  Control x; but you did not initialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the controls already exist on the form and you just want to set the location, call [Form.ControlCollection.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.controlcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a reference to the control from its name:

> Searches for controls by their Name property and builds an array of
>   all the controls that match

So, something like this:

```
Control x = this.Controls.Find(controlName, true).FirstOrDefault();

if (x != null)  
    x.Location = new Point(xCoord, yCoord);
```

Comment: That's the solution.  Thank you.