# c# use unassigned local variable

Tags: c#

hi this is my code i want to add string in list but i get this error

> use of unassigned local variable

and this is my code

```
List<string> tokens = new List<string>();
int token_number=0 ;
char[] character = file_text.ToCharArray();
int i = 0;
for (; i < character.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsLetter(character[i]))
    {
        string local_token;
        while (char.IsLetterOrDigit(character[i + 1]) || character[i + 1] == '_')
        {

            local_token += character[i];
            tokens.Add(local_token.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

hi this is my code and i want to add string to my list so get this error `Error 2   Use of unassigned local variable 'local_token'  C:\Users\Alireza\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\tslnc\tslnc\Program.cs   46  25  tslnc`

Comment: Your string `local_token` is not an empty string but `null` when you don't initialize it. Then you can't use it and `local_token += character[i]` will fail with a `NullReferenceException` at runtime anyway. That's what the compiler wants to tell you. You just have to assign a value like `""`.
`

Comment: Apart from the answers below, also note that you should probably be adding `local_token` to `tokens` OUTSIDE the `while` loop.

Comment: Would it not be worth using a `StringBuilder` for this rather than appending using `+`?

Comment: [Why compile error “Use of unassigned local variable”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233000/why-compile-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable)

Comment: [Fields (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare a variable:

```
string local_token;
```

Then you try to reference its value:

```
local_token += character[i];
```

But you never *gave* it a value.  It's *null*.  It's *unassigned*.

Simply declare it with a default value:

```
string local_token = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your declaration of the local_token to this:

```
string local_token = "";
```

If you don't specify a value for the string it isn't initialized (unassigned).

Comment: A little explanation would be great

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing very simple one liner answer:-

```
You are only generating new instance, but you didn't assigned with any value, So you are getting run time error.
```

> string local_token;
>
> local_token = string.empty;

Now just add 2nd line also in your code. Hope this post will make more help :).

Answer (score 0):

you have to intialize variable before use...

```
 string local_token=string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on others answers, rather than using a `string` for `local_token` you could use a `Stringbuilder`.

In a loop, a `Stringbuilder` will be a lot faster and use a lot less memory than appending to a `string` using `+` ("[How to improve string concatenation performance in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306822)").

To implement the `Stringbuilder`:

```
   StringBuilder local_token = new Stringbuilder();
    while (char.IsLetterOrDigit(character[i + 1]) || character[i + 1] == '_')
    {
        local_token.Append(character[i]);
        tokens.Add(local_token.ToString());
        local_token.Clear();
    }
```