# Using a reference parameter

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# by myself by book and would appreciate some help. I want to create a simple console program to allow the user to enter a number to be doubled. It says that the variable `result` in the Main method is unassigned, however, what am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
class Program
{

    private static void Double(ref int num, ref int result)
    {
        result = num * 2;

    }

    private static int readNumber(string question)
    {
        Console.Write(question);
        string ans = Console.ReadLine();
        int number = int.Parse(ans);
        return number;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int num, result;
        num = readNumber("Enter an integer to be doubled: ");
        Double(ref num, ref result);
        Console.WriteLine("The double of {0} is {1}", num, result);
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want `out int result` in the method signature. But most of the time I'd do it without using `ref`and `out` alltogether ....

Comment: yep, it says that the variable result in the Main method is unassigned. Yeah but I want to practice `ref`

Comment: Use `out` instead of `ref`. Even better, don't use them at all if you don't have to.

Comment: [Possible Duplicate - Why compile error “Use of unassigned local variable”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9233000/1324033)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is yelling at you because it wants to force you to initialize the variables before passing them to the method call.

Meaning:

```
int num, result;
```

Should be:

```
int num = 0;
int result = 0;
```

There may be a better way of doing what you're trying to do, without any `ref` parameters at all, by simply using the return value of the method:

```
private static int Double(int num)
{
    return num * 2;
}
```

And consume it like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int num = readNumber("Enter an integer to be doubled: ");
    int result = Double(num);
    Console.WriteLine("The double of {0} is {1}", num, result);
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This may even (IMO) enhance the readability of your code and convey your intentions better.

Answer (score 0):

´Why don´t you simply change the methods signatur to return a double instead of using a `ref`?

```
private static double Double(int num)
{
    return num * 2;
}
```

Now you can simply call `result = Double(num)`.

Comment: And remove the parameter `result`, it's now unnecessary/confusing