# c# foreach loop access variable

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, unassigned-variable

I have the following problem:
i have a string variable, which has to store a filepath.
In a foreach loop i go through all files in a certain directory and im looking for the oldest, which is saved in that string variable.
When the loop is finished i try to delete that file, but i get an error:
Use of an unassigned local variable.

Here is the code:

```
DateTime min = DateTime.Now;
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(somePath);
string fileDelete;
int countFiles = fileNames.Length;
if (countfiles > 5)
{
    foreach (string someFile in fileNames)
    {
        FileInfo infoFile = new FileInfo(someFile);
        if (infoFile.CreationTime <= min)
        {
            min = infoFile.CreationTime;
            fileDelete = someFile;
        }   
    }
    File.Delete(fileDelete);
}
```

it says that the string fileDelete in File.Delete(fileDelete) has no value,
but the fun thin is, when i give it a value at the beginning just like that:

```
string fileDelete = "blabla";
```

it works perfectly fine.
This is just a snipped of the method in case you are wondering

Comment: When you do `string fileDelete = "blabla";`, the variable is no longer unassigned. Is `countFiles` bigger than `5`? Does at least one file have a creation time before `DateTime.Now`? Your code does not guarantee that `fileDelete` is assigned, so it's going to go wrong at some point.

Comment: As others said, compiler can only work with variable when it is initialized explicitly. So just use `string fileDelete = "";`

Comment: Thank you all for your awnsers. I understand the problem now. I just forgot that the compiler can not know that condition 2 is always met when condition 1 is (in my programm), and the compiler saw a case, where File.Delete will be executed without a value, even though this can not happen in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works exactly as intended.

In C# local variables are not initialised automatically at declaration.

You're not assinging any value to the `fileDelete` when declaring it and assigning it only under some condition in your loop.

But you're trying to use its value outside this condition in loop, thus compiler can't deduce - will `fileDelete` has some value at runtime or not (if code under condition will not be executed - then `fileDelete` will has no value).

Thus compiler generates this error.

Comment: thats right thank you. I just forgot that the compiler can not know that condition 2 is always met when condition 1 is (in my programm).

Answer (score 3):

in C# you have to initialise variables, otherwise you could pass garbage values to File.Delete.

I recommend using

```
string fileDelete = null; // or ""
```

and later check for that.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileDelete))
{
  File.Delete(fileDelete);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this scenario:

- `countFiles > 5` is True
- `infoFile` for `someFile` is bigger than `min`

What value will `fileDelete` have when passed to `File.Delete`?

Answer: In such scenario `fileDelete` will be uninitialized, thus the error message.

Comment: Thats 100% right. I just didn't see that case because it can not happen in my program, but of course the compiler thinks it could happen.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize your variable.
see at                                       [Why compile error "Use of unassigned local variable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233000/why-compile-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
DateTime min = DateTime.Now;
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(somePath);
string fileDelete;
int countFiles = fileNames.Length;
if (countfiles > 5)
{
    foreach (string someFile in fileNames)
    {
        FileInfo infoFile = new FileInfo(someFile);
        if (infoFile.CreationTime <= min)
        {
            min = infoFile.CreationTime;
            fileDelete = someFile;
            File.Delete(fileDelete);
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: this would make fileDelete redundant completely

Comment: I didn't test this but i think this will just delete all files that are older than now. But i wanted to delete only the oldest file in a certain directory