# C# Use of unassigned local variable c

Tags: c#

I'm getting the following error:

> Use of unassigned local variable.

[image]

**Code:**

```
int c;
for (int b = 1; b < 5; b++)
{
    c = b * 2;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why compile error "Use of unassigned local variable"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233000/why-compile-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable)

Comment: :)) oh. I fogot it when compiled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace

```
int c;
```

with

```
int c = 0; //or some other initial value
```

The error appears because the compiler doesn't know if the loop is ever excecuted / a value is assigned to c. So it doesn't allow you to use it `Console.WriteLine(c);`

```
int c; // this works because the compiler knows there is a values assigned to c
c = 1;
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Comment: +1 Thanks :)
How to have :
" b * ( each element of sloop)" like : 1*(1+2+3+4)
And multiply each element in sloop like : 1*2*3*4

Comment: @HungNguyen - this is a separate question. Please post accordingly and be sure to show what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a value to variable `c` before using it. like

```
int c = 1;
```