# How to do "if else" to check if array is empty .cshtml file

Tags: c#, html, arrays

i would like to know how to resolve the issue "Use of unassigned local variable 'votesArr'. 
I would like to check if the array is empty first before i do the splitting ',' to store the data inside.

My image is inside the link provided.
Please advise. Thanks

[Image is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoCmy.png)

Comment: You need to initialize the variable first before you do a comparison. That said, checking for null after declaring it as null doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: You have literally just declared that variable. It would never have anything at this point. The error message correctly tells you that. I'm not sure what is there to fix - either don't do that check or assign a value to the variable.

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied to reproduce the issue, aren't searchable for future readers and harder to read than text. Please post the actual code as text to create a [mcve].

Comment: Also, is this JavaScript or C#?

Comment: You should move that if condition after `File.ReadAllText()` and then check it's value.

Comment: I downvoted because [no MCVE](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) and [Images of Code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Use of unassigned local variable c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393671/c-sharp-use-of-unassigned-local-variable-c)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you can not use an unassigned variable. here you can just assign a null to the votesArr, I mean:

```
string[] votesArr = null;
```

Comment: But if you do this, what's the point of putting `if (votesArr == null)` after it? The condition would always be true.

Comment: Yeap, I know. I'v just answered the question, saying "i would like to know how to resolve the issue "Use of unassigned local variable 'votesArr'.". Using an unassigned variable is not possible, If wanna use it elsewhere without assigning, must assign null to it.