# Why double area = 0;?

Tags: c#

Just a newbie to c# looking for some guidance.

In the below code if I used double area; it would give me the error : "Use of unassigned local variable area". I had to put double area = 0;

My question is why? Why do I have to assign it a value. I have never had to do that before so it's a bit confusing to me.

Thanks in advance for your response.

```
      int userValue, rad, heightOfRectangle, widthOfRectangle, baseOfTriangle, heightOfTriangle;
        double area = 0;

        Console.Write("\n\n");
        Console.Write("Calculating Area of Geometrical Shape\n");
        Console.Write("=======================================\n");
        Console.Write("\n\n");
        Console.Write("Please select 1 for Circle, 2 for Rectangle and 3 for Triangle: ");

        userValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (userValue)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.Write("Please Enter Radius of Circle: ");
                rad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                area = 3.14 * rad * rad;
                break;

            case 2:
                Console.Write("Please enter Height of Rectangle: ");
                heightOfRectangle  = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Please enter Width of Rectangle: ");
                widthOfRectangle = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                area = widthOfRectangle * heightOfRectangle;
                break;

            case 3:
                Console.Write("Please enter Base of Triangle: ");
                baseOfTriangle = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Please enter height of Triangle: ");
                heightOfTriangle = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                area = .5 * baseOfTriangle * heightOfTriangle;
                break;

        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nThe area is {0}", area);
```

Comment: What happens if `userValue` is equal to 4? What would be the value of `area` if you didn't initialize it?

Comment: It's called defensive programming.

Comment: For best-practice, please put the `default` case in `switch statement`

Comment: The lack of a default case in your switch case means that there is a possible execution path which result in `area` not being initialised prior to it being read.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine that user input `123` on

> "Please select 1 for Circle, 2 for Rectangle and 3 for Triangle:

question. In this case `area` will not have been assigned (no `case` will be executed) and

```
 Console.WriteLine("\nThe area is {0}", area);
```

will not have an idea what to output

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. I understand now .

Answer (score 1):

As stated, it is good practice to initialize the variable to ensure it has a value and avoid a possible exception error by having it called without being assigned any value. In addition, adding a "goto" placement will allow you to return to the starting point (although I'd rather you create separate methods for this)

```
        int userValue, rad, heightOfRectangle, widthOfRectangle, baseOfTriangle, heightOfTriangle;
        double area;

        Console.Write("\n\n");
        Console.Write("Calculating Area of Geometrical Shape\n");
        Console.Write("=======================================\n");
        Console.Write("\n\n");

        Start:

        Console.Write("Please select 1 for Circle, 2 for Rectangle and 3 for Triangle: ");

        userValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (userValue)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.Write("Please Enter Radius of Circle: ");
                rad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                area = 3.14 * rad * rad;
                break;

            case 2:
                Console.Write("Please enter Height of Rectangle: ");
                heightOfRectangle = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Please enter Width of Rectangle: ");
                widthOfRectangle = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                area = widthOfRectangle * heightOfRectangle;
                break;

            case 3:
                Console.Write("Please enter Base of Triangle: ");
                baseOfTriangle = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Please enter height of Triangle: ");
                heightOfTriangle = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                area = .5 * baseOfTriangle * heightOfTriangle;
                break;
            default:
                goto Start;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nThe area is {0}", area);
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: I like that goto Start. It's new for me and I think I will start using it from now on! :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for error is that it can happen that non of the cases in your `switch` statement occur - e.g. the user makes a wrong input.

Also local variables are not initialized with the default value, thus area has no value if non of the case statements are executed [Why compile error "Use of unassigned local variable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233000/why-compile-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable)

Comment: Variable `area` is a value-type, it will never be `null`, because it's not a valid value. It will simply be uninitialized and not pass the compilation.