# How to I get the date difference in days between present date and the other date is coming in as a string?

Tags: c#

```
string upgradeDate = "";
TimeSpan dateDifference;

if (!sqlDR.IsDBNull(3)) upgradeDate = sqlDR.GetString(3);
dateDifference = (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(upgradeDate)).TotalDays;
```

`upgradeDate` is coming in from the database as string. I am also getting an unassigned  variable error for `upgradeDate` in the last line.

Comment: Presumably this doesn't compile? `TotalDays` returns a double value, but you're trying to assign that to `dateDifference` which is defined as a TimeSpan..

Comment: Any idea why I am getting the unassigned variable error for upgradeDate in the last line?

Comment: If possible I would suggest that you always save dates in a DB in a date data type and not as a string.

Comment: [Why compile error “Use of unassigned local variable”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233000/why-compile-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable)

Comment: @stuartd Except that `upgradeDate` is assigned.  Makes me really wonder if this is the actual code that produced that compilation error.

Comment: @juharr dateDifference isn't assigned..

Comment: @stuartd But it's not being used, it's actually being assigned the wrong type, so I would expect this code to give a compilation error about implicitly converting a `double` to a `TimeSpan`.  In fact the only way this code gives the error the OP is talking about is if you remove the `= ""` from the first line.

Comment: @juharr oh yes. I got confused by the code: yet another case of confusion caused by improper formatting of `if` clauses

Answer (score 2):

You can go this way:

```
TimeSpan? dateDifference = null;

if (!sqlDR.IsDBNull(3)) {
   string upgradeDate = sqlDR.GetString(3);
   dateDifference = DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(upgradeDate);
}
```

If `sqlDR.IsDBNull(3)` then `dateDifference` will be null.

You can also start with `TimeSpan dateDifference = TimeSpan.Zero;` It's up to you.

But for sure you have to read this: [Why compile error "Use of unassigned local variable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233000/why-compile-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable), as @stuartd said.

Comment: Cannot assign `double` to `TimeSpan?`.  You'll need to remove the `.TotalDays`.