# C# Local variable might not be initialized before accessing, in a Try-Catch-Finally

Tags: c#, local-variables, try-catch-finally

Maybe I am missing something obvious. Consider the following code:

```
string str;
try
{
    str = "";
}
catch (Exception)
{
    str = "";
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
Console.WriteLine(str); //this compiles
```

Here the compiler shows the well-known error **CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'str'**. I know I can fix it by doing `string str = null`. But, in which execution path does **str** might not be initialized?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why compile error "Use of unassigned local variable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233000/why-compile-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable)

Comment: Could be one of the items in the downvote tooltip: "This question does not show any research effort".

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, I do not see the try-catch-finally case in that question

Comment: It has nothing to do with try/catch/finally. it has too do with variable scope.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Just because you've answered a question doesn't make it not a duplicate...

Comment: Yes, @MichaelPuckettII is right. I have just edited the question and the compilers does not complains if I access the varaible after the finally block.

Comment: Right, moving it outside the try/catch/finally block *changes its scope*.

Comment: So,please, what does variable scope has to do?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII wow, there's no threads involved here at all.

Comment: How using a variable after the finally block changes its scope?

Comment: The scope depends on where the variable is declared...

Comment: Personally I don't think it's got anything to do with scope (the variable is in scope for the whole of the code shown here) or threads (you don't need any threading concepts to explain this). See my answer for an alternative perspective :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give another way of looking at this that has nothing to do with threads: the compiler behaves this way *because that's the way the language is specified*.

From the ECMA C# 5 specification section 10.4.4.16:

> **Try-catch-finally statements**
>
> Definite assignment analysis for a `try-catch-finally` statement of the form:
>
> ```
> try try-block
> catch ( … ) catch-block-1
> …
> catch ( … ) catch-block-n
> finally finally-block
> ```
>
> is done as if the statement were a try-finally statement enclosing a try-catch statement:
>
> ```
> try {
>   try try-block
>   catch ( … ) catch-block-1
>    …
>   catch ( … ) catch-block-n
> }
> finally finally-block
> ```

So how does a try-finally statement work in terms of definite assignment? That's in section 10.4.4.16:

> For a `try` statement *stmt* of the form:
>
> try try-block finally finally-block
>
> - ...
> - The definite assignment state of *v* at the beginning of *finally-block* is the same as the definite assignment state of *v* at the beginning of *stmt*.

So what does that mean in your case? At the start of the statement, your variable `str` is not definitely assigned... so by those rules, it's *also* not definitely assigned at the start of the `finally` block.

Now, why was the language designed that way? That's a slightly different question. I don't think that has anything to do with threads. The language generally assumes that *anything* can throw an exception. The only way a variable becomes definitely assigned is for it to be assigned a value *and that assignment complete without throwing an exception*. Any code path that could occur even if an exception occurs before assignment cannot be considered to definitely assign the variable.

As a simple example, imagine we changed your code to:

```
string str;
try
{
    str = MethodThatThrowsAnException();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    str = MethodThatThrowsAnException();
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

At that point, it doesn't seem so odd that `str` is not definitely assigned. It's only because it's assigning a string literal that it looks like it can't possibly fail. But I could imagine even assigning a string literal failing, if it's the first time that string constant has been seen, and it needs to allocate a `String` object... that allocation could fail. Then there are all the other ways that exceptions can be thrown, including threads being aborted.

All of this means:

- The first statement in the `try` block can throw an exception
- The first statement in the `catch` block can throw an exception

In that situation - however that occurs, and whether it's got anything to do with threading or not (it could be an allocation failure, for example) - you won't have executed any assignment to `str`, so it has no defined value to read.

Comment: Well now it seems this may be the correct answer... It makes sense and it is in the language specification

Comment: For sake of completeness I will take the task of joining both answers in one superb answer =)... just after diapers changing and tale counting =) ... Thanks both

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII: I still disagree that this needs to have anything to do with threads. All you need to assume is that any statement can throw an exception without completing. Even in C# were specified to only ever run in a single-threaded environment, that would be enough to force the language to be written that way. Threads being aborted is *one* way that a simple assignment can throw, but there are others. I think explaining it without threads is simpler and more general, personally.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII: I've edited the answer to go more into the details of why the language specification assumes anything can throw. I'm not saying that threads being aborted isn't *one* way that we can end up with an exception in an unexpected way - but it's not the only way, and I think it leads to a more-complicated-than-required explanation.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I like your answer better.

Comment: @taquion Apologies, but I'm asking you change your answer to Daisy's.  I believe it is more relevant to your question where my answer, although relevant, may belong to a question more suited to threading.  Threading or not, the bottom line is, when we hit try then finally will be called and if for any reason the assignment fails to be made in try or catch via exception or a new / repeat exception etc; finally will attempt to use the variable. If assigned in try and or catch we can't guarantee that code runs completely but we can guarantee finally... Even when threading.