# How to fix 'error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable' in XmlReader Switch Case

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I try to read data from a Xml file. 
My plan is to save all students as an object of Student with the name and the semester.

```
<persons>
    <student><name>255211</name><semester>MI</semester></student>
    <student><name>255212</name><semester>MI</semester></student>
    <student><name>255213</name><semester>MI</semester></student>
</persons>
```

I found a guide with XmlReader and switch case so i tried it.

```
private static void readData()
        {
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("data.xml");

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    switch (reader.Name)
                    {
                        case "student":
                            Student student = new Student();
                            Students.Add(student);
                            break;
                        case "name":
                            student.name = reader.ReadString();
                            //Console.WriteLine(student.name);
                            break;
                        case "semester":
                            student.semester = reader.ReadString();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
```

My problem now is that Visual Studio Code gives me an error:
error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'student' (student.name in case "name"). I guess it is because there wouldn't be a student.name if the code does not go into case "student". I tried with try catch but that didn't helped me.

How can I achieve that every student gets his name and semester correct?

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233000/why-compile-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only *assign* `student` in the `"student"` case; from the compiler's point of view, `student` is unassigned at the start of the `"name"` and `"semester"` cases, so you can't set properties on them. You might have knowledge that `<student>` always comes first, but the *compiler* doesn't know that. Also, from it's view, the scope is separate for each element. But if you're *100% sure* that there's always a `<student>` between each then you could probably move the assignment around a little:

```
Student student = null;
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        switch (reader.Name)
        {
            case "student":
                student = new Student();
                Students.Add(student);
                break;
            case "name":
                student.name = reader.ReadString();
                //Console.WriteLine(student.name);
                break;
            case "semester":
                student.semester = reader.ReadString();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, in reality, in most scenarios, I would strongly recommend using `XmlSerializer` or similar to parse the input into objects, and then just deal with them as objects.

Based on the xml layout in the question, this should work:

```
public class Student {
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("semester")]
    public string Semester {get;set;}
}
[XmlRoot("persons")]
public class SomeData {
    [XmlElement("student")]
    public List<Student> Students {get;} = new List<Student>();
}
```

and:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeData));
var data = (SomeData)ser.Deserialize(source);
List<Student> students = data.Students;
```

Comment: I've deleted my similar answer. Thinking about it, I prefer this version that throws a `NullReferenceException` if the assumption is violated rather than continuing on regardless but it still only saves you from an initial leading `name` or `semester` element.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever my preference is actually for the bit I've just edited in :)