# C# Checking if Object is Null

Tags: c#, ssis

I am having trouble with an if statement for checking if an object is null.

I have a webClient go and pull a JSON string from a website in a try/catch. If it errors, it is because the 3 digit country does not exist in the API and I just want to skip it.

Here is my code:

```
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();

    RootObject ro;
    try
    {
        string resp = wc.DownloadString("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/" + Row.Code.ToString());

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        ro = js.Deserialize<RootObject>(resp);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { }

    if (ro.Region != null)
    {
        Row.Region = ro.Region;
        Row.SubRegion = ro.Subregion;
    }
```

RootObject is a class to deserialize to. This works fine.

However, I am getting an error in the if statement that "use of unassigned class 'ro'.

Can someone help me fix this? ro works as expected inside the if?

I have also tried checking a specific node and it is still getting hung up on the 'ro' part.

Also, this is a script component in SSIS.

Thanks

Comment: If an error is thrown and the `catch` path is executed `ro` is not initialized. That's why you get this error.

Comment: Then just assign it. What do you want the program to do if it's not assigned?

Comment: I want it to skip and exit. It is basically done if nothing is returned from the API

Comment: Change    RootObject ro to RootObject ro = null;   and change ro.Region != null to ro?.Region != null

Comment: Murray that solved it. I thought it started as null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why compile error "Use of unassigned local variable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233000/why-compile-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. It is possible that the `try` block will never assign a value to `ro` and thus it will be unassigned outside of try block. To fix that, assign a value:

   ```
   RootObject ro = null;
   ```
2. Since `ro` could be `null`, you need to check for that in your `if` statement before you try to access a member:

   ```
   if (ro != null && ro.Region != null)
   {
       Row.Region = ro.Region;
       Row.SubRegion = ro.Subregion;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Solving this was really #1. I also changed the if to just if(ro!=null) and achieved desired results.

Answer (score 6):

Give `ro` a default value, so change `RootObject ro` to `RootObject ro = null;`

and change `ro.Region != null` to `ro?.Region != null` to allow for `ro` being null.

and possibly do something about swallowing that exception.

```
System.Net.WebClient wc;

RootObject ro = null;
try
{
    wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    string resp = wc.DownloadString("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/" + Row.Code.ToString());

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    ro = js.Deserialize<RootObject>(resp);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Log your error
}

if (ro?.Region != null)
{
    Row.Region = ro.Region;
    Row.SubRegion = ro.Subregion;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The object ro should be initialized ,cause it is called outside the try scope

```
RootObject ro = null;
try
{
    string resp = wc.DownloadString("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/" + Row.Code.ToString());

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    ro = js.Deserialize<RootObject>(resp);
}
catch (Exception e)
{ }

if (ro?.Region != null)
{
    Row.Region = ro.Region;
    Row.SubRegion = ro.Subregion;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialize `ro` with `RootObject ro = null;` and change the if statement to

```
if (ro?.Region != null)
{
    Row.Region = ro.Region;
    Row.SubRegion = ro.Subregion;
}
```

This way the statement will check if either ro is null or ro.Region is null